# How to change the values of socketid is changed after calling function

Tags: c

I am using following api to initialize sockfd at client side:(sockfd=3)

```
              if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol))  == -1) {
                    perror("client: socket");
                    continue;
            }
```

& initializing my TPKT_Buff to {3,0,0,0} value by using function :

```
            if(Fill_TPKT(PStack,TPKT_Buff) != 0)
  {
   printf("Error while filling TPKT Buffer");
   return 1;
  }printf("tpkt/2_Buff%x %x\n",TPKT_Buff[0],TPKT_Buff[1]);printf("sockfd=%d\n",sockfd);
```

But, after calling function :

```
 if(Fill_COTP(PStack,&cotp) != 0)
    {
     printf("Error while filling COTP Structure!");
     return 1;
    }
```

my socfd & TPKT_Buff values changed to zero TPKT_Buff={0,0,0,0} & sockfd=0 :

```
printf("sockfd=%d\n",sockfd);
 printf("TPKT/2_Buff=%x %x\n",TPKT_Buff[0],TPKT_Buff[1]);
```

Definitions of functions Fill_COTP & Fill_TPKT are as follows :

```
  int Fill_TPKT(FILE *fptr,unsigned char *buf)
  {
   fseek(fptr,14,SEEK_SET);
   fscanf(fptr,"%d",buf+0);

   fseek(fptr,15,SEEK_CUR); 
   fscanf(fptr,"%d",buf+1);

   return 0;
  }

 int Fill_COTP(FILE *fptr, COTP *cotp)
 {
  unsigned short temp;

  fseek(fptr,13,SEEK_CUR);
  fscanf(fptr,"%d",&temp);
  cotp->Destination_Ref[1] = temp;
  cotp->Destination_Ref[0] = temp>>8;
  printf("%x %x\n",cotp->Destination_Ref[0],cotp->Destination_Ref[1]);
  fseek(fptr,13,SEEK_CUR);
  fscanf(fptr,"%d",&temp);
  cotp->Source_Ref[1] = temp;
  cotp->Source_Ref[0] = temp>>8;
  printf("%x %x\n",cotp->Source_Ref[0],cotp->Source_Ref[1]);
  fseek(fptr,14,SEEK_CUR);
  fscanf(fptr,"%d",&temp);
  cotp->Source_Tsap[1] = temp;
  cotp->Source_Tsap[0] = temp>>8;
  printf("%x %x\n",cotp->Source_Tsap[0],cotp->Source_Tsap[1]);
  fseek(fptr,14,SEEK_CUR);
  fscanf(fptr,"%d",&temp);
  cotp->Destination_Tsap[1] = temp;
  cotp->Destination_Tsap[0] = temp>>8;
  printf("%x %x\n",cotp->Destination_Tsap[0],cotp->Destination_Tsap[1]);
  fseek(fptr,17,SEEK_CUR);
  fscanf(fptr,"%d",&(cotp->TPDU_size));
  printf("%x\n",cotp->TPDU_size);
  return 0;
 }
```

Here PStack is a file pointer.
I am not getting why my sockfd & TPKT_Buff values changing to zero even I am not using these values in my function Fill_COTP();
Please give some suggestion.
Definition of COTP is:

```
       typedef struct
         {
          unsigned char PDU_type;
          unsigned char Destination_Ref[2];
          unsigned char Source_Ref[2];
          unsigned char Source_Tsap[2];
          unsigned char Destination_Tsap[2];
          unsigned char TPDU_size;
         } COTP;
```

There is no relation between sockfd & TPKT_Buff.

Comment: Can you please care more about how you **indent** your code?

Comment: Please provide the definitions for the COTP structure.

Comment: is there any relation between `sockfd` and `TPKT_Buff`? i mean pointing?? and COTP any pointing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble appears to be in the line:

```
fscanf(fptr,"%d",&(cotp->TPDU_size));
```

Your TPCU_size is `unsigned char TPDU_size;` which is only 1 byte (assuming this to be the size of 'char') in size, but you are trying put 4 bytes (assuming that to be the size of 'int') into it during fscanf, thereby potentially overwriting the memory around it.

Comment: So, can I use "%c" in place of "%d"

Comment: Try it and see. Is your TPKT_Buff and sockfd declared below COTP in your code?

Comment: Yeah COTP is declared before TPKT_Buff & sockfd and it worked

Comment: Thanks for your help with the change you mentioned I also chaned my local temp variable in Fill_COTP() to int and problem resolved.Thanks

Comment: "%c" not worked out I copied value to temporary variable first and then to structure's value.

Answer (score 0):

While there is some information missing, some of what you have shown is clearly wrong and is likely to be involved in the problem.  For instance:

```
int Fill_TPKT(FILE *fptr,unsigned char *buf)
  {
   fseek(fptr,14,SEEK_SET);
   fscanf(fptr,"%d",buf+0);

   fseek(fptr,15,SEEK_CUR); 
   fscanf(fptr,"%d",buf+1);
```

If each call to `fscanf` works, each will fill in one `int`, but `buf` points to a sequence of `unsigned char`s.  Unless you have very large `char`s and `sizeof(int) == 1` this is obviously wrong.

The same mistake is repeated at many other points, e.g., in `Fill_COTP`, `fscanf` with a `%d` directive is used to fill in `temp`, which has type `unsigned short` rather than `int`.

You could change the directives (`%hhd` will fill in a single `char` and `%hd` will fill in a single `short`; `%hhu` and `%hu` will fill in `unsigned char` and `unsigned short`).  However, simply calling `fscanf` like this, without any error checking, is not very robust.  If the contents of the input stream are not convert-able to the target type, the call will fail (`fscanf` will return either EOF or a short count, depending on the kind of failure, "input" vs "matching", and the point of the failure).  You might want a little intermediate function that does appropriate error checking, perhaps scanning into an `int` after all and then range-checking the value for instance.

Comment: Thanks for figurring out the problem I changed it and now my code working happily. I am now careful about this mistake.